# Laravel | Как сделать отправку письма на Email при сбросе пароля или регистрации?

Tags: php, laravel, api, email, auth

Есть вход, регистрация, выход и т.д, сделанные с помощью `php artisam make:auth`.

Не работает сброс пароля, не отправляется письмо.
Можете подсказать новичку как это реализовать (желательно попроще).

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#reset-email-customization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Laravel есть встроенный контроллер для сброса пароля Auth\ResetPasswordController.php

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Blog\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Blog\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
}
```

Вьюха лежит здесь /resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php (пример)

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Reset Password') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('password.update') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ $email ?? old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Reset Password') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```